# How to translate all bones of an armature in pose mode without destroying the animation?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

I have a simple blender file with a mixamo animation imported as fbx. The animation is pushed down to the NLA and I have added a new (corrective) NLA track to do some tweakings. On this new NLA track I have a new action which includes a keyframe at the first frame of the animation in which i moved the whole armature (in pose mode) along the x axis. I just want to move the whole animation on the x axis (but not the object!) but this totally destroys the animation (random bone movement).

[image]

Blend-Exchange:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/ Why not moving the whole object?

Comment: @moonboots I added my blender file. I want to get a smooth transition between two mixamo animations but they have been captured with totally different (translated) armature positions in pose mode (while object/armature origin is the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your corrective layer's Blending mode: it is set to "Replace".

[image: replace blend]

That means, whatever keyframe you put in that layer is considered as the new value for the corresponding bone.

When you are editing an action in the action editor, you can access its Blending mode in the NLA editor by selecting the top track which represents the Action Editor.

*Add* is usually the simplest, though sometimes you will want *Multiply*. Feel free to experiment.

Though be aware, you should avoid keying any parameter or controllers that you don't want to change. Especially scale.

Here's how it looks when just keying the hip bone when moves up one unit in global space:

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you. It looks like the key to success is to really only keying the relevant bone and properties (in this case Translation), as you have already pointed out. "Combine" worked fine for me. +1

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it the way you are trying to do it, select the parent bone (bottom spine), select its *X Location* track only (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to hide the other tracks, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to make them come back), move its curve on Y in the *Graph Editor*:

[image]

Comment: Correct result, but the destructive way without layers.

Comment: I began by creating an action for the spine bone only (if this is what you mean) and delete all the other bones keyframes, but I was not entirely sure what he wanted  ;)

Comment: Let me reformulate:  you used layers as a backup to make a change in a destructive way that doesn't make use of what layers are excellent at: iterative changes. It's like in photoshop the difference between duplicating layers and paint new stuff on the duplicate, instead of creating a new empty layer on top and draw completely new things on it. None of the methods are wrong, just different. 

Comment: @moonboots Thank you for answering my question. Your solution works, but I was looking for a non-destructive way.